# Fundamental points of Cremona plane transformation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, birational-geometry

The Cremona plane transformation is the birational map $\varphi: \Bbb P^2 \to \Bbb P^2$, defined by $[x:y:z] \mapsto [yz:xz:xy]$ on the every point except for $[0:0:1]$ , $[0:1:0]$ , $[0:0:1]$.
I want to show that $\varphi$ can't be extended to one of the special points, as a morphism from an open subspace of the projective plane, to the projective plane.
I tried lifting the question to $\Bbb A^3$ but did not succeed.

I would love to get an advice or a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Lifting sounds like a good approach. There should be a map $\mathbb{A}^3 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}^2$, and the Cremona transformation lifts to a map $\mathbb{A}^3 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{A}^3 \setminus \{0\}$: it must be the similar-looking map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (yz,xz,xy)$. This should allow you to infer what the value of $[1 : 0 : 0]$ and $[0 : 1 : 0]$ and $[0 : 0 : 1]$ should be if an extension were to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U = \mathbb{P}^2 \setminus \{P_0, P_1,P_2\}$ where $P_i$ are the points. We try to extend $\varphi$ past $U$. For points $p \in V_p(x_1)$ we have $$\varphi(p) = \varphi([p_0, 0, p_2]) = [0, p_0 p_2, 0] = [0,1,0].$$ For $p \in V_p(x_2)$ we see that the rational map gives $\varphi(p) = [0,0,1]$. Define $r_\lambda = [p, 0, \lambda]$ and $s_\lambda = [p, \lambda, 0]$. Then $$\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \varphi(r_\lambda) = [0,1,0] \text{ and } \lim_{\lambda \to 0} \varphi(s_\lambda) = [0,0,1].$$ But $\lim_{\lambda \to 0} r_\lambda = s_\lambda = [1,0,0]$ so that if $\varphi$ extends to $P_0$ then $\varphi(P_0) = [0,1,0] = [0,0,1]$ which is a contradiction. By symmetry we see that $\varphi$ does not extend to $P_1, P_2$.